# use Amazon RDS as slave in mysql replication

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I have one server where mysql is running, its a VM. I am currently configuring another mysql in in Amazon RDS. Can I use this RDS database as a slave of the VM database. So I want the VM DB to be the master of the replication and the RDS database be the slave.

Is it at all possible? Or any other option?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it is possible, though this would not be a recommended setup.

RDS provides a built in procedure you can call to set this up.  Rather than me explaining the procedure here, I will simply link you to the documentation.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/mysql_rds_set_external_master.html

What this doesn't tell you is that you must have taken a consistent DB dump from the master DB and installed it on the RDS instance.  You must also have obviously recorded the binary log position information when taking that consistent dump, so you have that information to use in the procedure.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the reply +1. Can you please tell me what will be the best method for me to achieve this. If you can give me any other recommendation. Thanks again.

Comment: @APaul Sorry I should have been clearer. I just meant that trying to manage a replicated MySQL setup across two different infrastructures is likely going to be problematic and require a lot more effort on your part to maintain. If you are looking at using RDS, I personally would put both master and slave in RDS and utilize the built-in replication functionality that RDS provides.  With the functionality it is literally a push of a button or command line statement to set up a read-only replica from a master database. The Amazon RDS service also provides redundant multi-AZ failover on the master

Comment: @APaul The failover obviously requires setting up master instance as multi-AZ and doesn't come for free (it is double the cost for this type of set-up), but significantly mitigates any availability concerns one would have for a typical application.

Comment: @MikeBrant: Doesn't this replicate all the databases on the master to the slave? What if you only want to replicate one of the databases from the 'master" to the slave?

Comment: @mtnpaul Yes. An RDS read replica will replicate all user DB's/Tables in the RDS master.

Comment: @MikeBrant Why is it not recommended?

Comment: @AndreasBergström If one would be moving their DB infrastructure into RDS, they could simplify the management of that infrastructure by using the built in RDS replication capabilities. Why introduce the fragility of managing a replicated infrastructure across two different data centers?

Comment: @MikeBrant As I understand the OP, he wants to use RDS as real-time backup. I'm considering using RDS like this, while keeping the master (and the rest of the app) outside of AWS.

Comment: @AndreasBergström Yes, and it is feasible to do, I just don't know why someone would want to do it.  To me, I would rather simplify the complexity of the infrastructure rather than introduce additional complexities of having a replication set up across different data centers/hosting providers.